# Suppose that we have square matrices of the same order such that $A-B=AB$, is $AB=BA$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Suppose that we have square matrices of the same order such that $A-B=AB$, is $AB=BA$ true?

I attempted this question by multiplying $B^{-1}$ to both sides of $A-B=AB$:

$B^{-1}A-B^{-1}B=ABB^{-1}$

$B^{-1}A-I=A-(1)$

Then, sub $(1)$ in $BA$, we get:

$B(B^{-1}A-I)=BB^{-1}A-IB=I(A-B)=A-B$

Since it is given that $A-B=AB$, we can conclude that $BA=AB$. Hence, it is true.

Can someone please let me know if this is a valid proof? My method seems a bit iffy to me.

Comment: In your first step, first of all you are assuming $B$ to be invertible, and you either multiply on the left or on the right, since you don't know yet whether $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: Yes, You must decide if the multiplication is from the left or right. Either $B^{-1}AB$ or $AB^{-1} - BB^{-1}$ but no mixture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem in the proof proposed by OP is twofold. On the one hand $B$ is not assumed to be invertible. Even assuming it is, one can multiply $A - B = A B$ by $B^{-1}$ either on the left, to get
$$
B^{-1} A - I = B^{-1} A B,
$$
or on the right, to get
$$
A B^{-1} - I = A.
$$
Since $A$ and $B$ are not known to commute yet, the two results might conceivably be different.

---

The assumption $A - B = A B$ implies
$$
(A + I) (I - B) = A - A B + I - B = I,
$$
so that $A + I$ and $I - B$ are invertible, and 
$$
I - B = (A + I)^{-1}.
$$
Then 
$$
I = (I - B) (A + I) = A + I - B A - B,
$$
which yields
$$
B A = A - B = A B.
$$

Comment: Are they also invertible the other way around? I.e. if considering $(I-B)(A+I)$

Comment: Hi, the OP asks also whether his/her proof is correct. Would you please move your comments here, so that I can up-vote your answer?

Comment: @user1551, sure thing, thanks!

Comment: @mathreadler, yes, when it comes to square matrices, being invertible on the right entails being invertible on the left (they are both equivalent to having non-zero determinant), and then the inverse is unique.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation and for pointing out my mistake! I understand where I have gone wrong now.

Comment: @iamaweed, you're welcome, I am glad to have been able to help. And thank you for giving me the final push to 50k ;-)

Comment: Honored to help you hit that impressive milestone! ;-)

Comment: Congratulations to 50K !!

Comment: Right on, @iamaweed. ;)