# If A and B are square matrices of same order such that AB=A+B then prove that AB=BA

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I tried everything to get the proof but I haven't reached a method yet..

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you *have* tried?  Clearly you haven't done “everything” yet because otherwise you would be done.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Letting $A'=A-I, B'=B-I$ then the above means that $A'B'=I.$ So show that thus $B'A'=I.$ (Here $I$ is the identity matrix.)

Comment: I tried squaring and multiplying it by A and B

Comment: Thomas has given a good hint.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2168444/9464